# Can't see the Facebook Feed - Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have a problem, I have followed the steps to get scoring the feed of a facebook page in my application and does not show anything.
What did I do wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/540165132697003",
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    // Insert your code here
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "feed");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();


}
```

Comment: What do you get in the `onCompleted` callback? try the same call with the access token use in the Graph API Explorer and see what you get there. Moreover, try to add the edge to the path instead of param: `"/540165132697003/feed",

Comment: The onCompleted callback was raised automaticly... And i didn't get anything :(

Comment: What do you mean by "raised"? is it being called? also have you tried the same call in the Graph API Explorer?